# sql query to subtract two table values and save them in first table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, oracle10g

How do I subtract one table column value from another table column value, and save the value in the first table column in the process?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are those two tables related(primary-foreign key)? Based on what conditions you want two columns of different tables to be subtracted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `tablename` is the table and `col1` is the first column and `col2` is the second column.

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1 = (col2 - col1)
```

If you are meaning that the values are coming from different tables then the query is much the same:

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1 = ((SELECT col2 from tablename2) - col1)
```

Comment: I wonder if op meant this or substracting the values of columns from different tables, the question is really vague

Comment: Edited by answer after [Lamaks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/519216/lamak) comment.

Comment: You're assuming the tables have only 1 row, or that you don't care which row's value you get.

Comment: Actually, the query will work on all rows in the set (the update will be applied for each row). Of course, if you wanted this to only be applied to a single row you could use a WHERE clause to specify a row in the update and the subselect

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for, but pick your example:

```
update CarBrand 
set SortIndex =  (select SortIndex from CarBrand where CarBrandId = 3615) + 7
where CarBrandId = 3619

update CarBrand
set SortIndex = SortIndex - OtherColumn
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without details about your tables or how they're related, but you might want something like

```
UPDATE t1
SET col = t1.col - t2.col
FROM mytable t1
JOIN myothertable t2 ON t2.pkCol = t1.pkCol
```